# Visual Studio Code vs SQL Formatting

Tags: sql, visual-studio-code

I downloaded Visual Studio Code thinking it would be nice to write T-SQL scripts and have the pretty auto-formatting happen as write.

I've already installed the mssql extension.

When creating a new file, the file is a simple plaintext with no extension 'Untitled-1'.

How in the world do I tell VS Code this is a SQL script so it formats correctly?

If I hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, I simply receive the error "There is no formatter for 'plaintext' installed."

If I save the file with the extension '.sql', the format is applied.

However, I don't want to have to save the file... I want it to just be a scratchpad.

Is there any way in VS Code to tell the editor the file should be formatted SQL other than saving the file as an SQL file?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I hope this will be of some help to you.

If I understood you correctly, you can use first this shortcut:

```
Win: Ctrl+Shift+P / Mac: Cmd+Shift+p
```

And then type "Change Language Mode".

Also try and visit this link for additional info:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cymonk.sql-formatter

Also you can visit this link:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview
where you can find additional info about that, for example:

> **Changing the language for the selected file**
>
> In VS Code, we default the
> language support for a file based on its filename extension. However,
> at times you may wish to change language modes, to do this click on
> the language indicator - which is located on the right hand of the
> Status Bar. This will bring up the Select Language Mode drop-down
> where you can select another language for the current file.
>
> Tip: You can get the same drop-down by running the Change Language
> Mode command (Ctrl+K M).

Comment: `Ctrl+K M` + `SQL` > `press enter` saves the day everytime :-)

Answer (score 43):

This is what I did to format SQL queries:

1. Install the [**SQLTools**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mtxr.sqltools) extension
2. Open your query
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
4. Select "Format Document With"
5. Select SQLTools

Comment: Tip: add the following lines to the `settings.json` to format file automatically when saving ... ```"[sql]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "mtxr.sqltools"
    }```

Comment: formatting with SQLTools changes strings by adding spaces, anyway to disable that?

Comment: This is a cool hack, but this doesn't work when there are other interferring SQL extensions installed like Snowflake, I had to uninstall that for this to work.

Answer (score 9):

The other methods work, but the easy button is to click on **Plain Text** on the status bar
[image: Click on Plain Text in status bar]

and then type in "SQL" to use your favorite installed SQL extension

[image: Set SQL]

Answer (score 2):

When you have no option "Format Document Wiht..." or no SQL in Command Palette
[image]

or no SQLTools
[image]

you just need to install a SQLTools formatter: write in extensions filter:
`@popular category:formatters sql`

and install one (I installed SQLTools)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To format your SQL code in Visual Studio Code, you can follow these steps:

Go to "Settings" by either clicking on the gear icon in the lower left corner and selecting "Settings" or by using the shortcut a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + ,.

In the search bar at the top of the Settings pane, type "Format" and select "Editor: Default Formatter".

Choose "SQL Formatter" from the dropdown menu.

Install the VS Code SQL Formatter extension from the Visual Studio Code Marketplace.

Once the extension is installed, you can format your SQL code using the following steps:

Open the SQL file you want to format.
Go to "View" > "Command Palette" or simply use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>.
Type "Formatter" and select "Format Document".
Choose "SQL Formatter".

Answer (score 1):

*To Add 

some Extensions that looks good to me. 

(but these options on formatting are still not as many as I expected)*

- SqlTools

  - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mtxr.sqltools
  - (as others talked)
  - more than just a formatter
  - only few options on formatting (see link)

    - https://github.com/mtxr/vscode-sqltools/discussions/1032
    - https://vscode-sqltools.mteixeira.dev/en/playground/formatter (online demo)
- Prettier SQL VSCode *(recommended)*

  - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=inferrinizzard.prettier-sql-vscode
  - slightly more options on formatting
- pgFormatter

  - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradymholt.pgformatter
  - for PostgreSQL SQL
  - built base on the following

    - https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/pgformatter-v53-released-2493/
    - https://sqlformat.darold.net/ (online demo)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning pgFormatter. My favourite formatter so far.