# VSCode gives syntax error on SQL type as wrong when it is right

Tags: sql, postgresql, visual-studio-code, highlight

I have a SQL file that's parsed through a PostgreSQL database with no error and I have an annoying highlighting issue in VSCode. msgs is a type of an array of TEXTs.

```
CREATE TABLE users_chat
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id INTEGER,
    friend_id INTEGER,
    msgs TEXT[]
);
```

The [] is getting a red squiggly line and the file is red in the folder. It's annoying.

What can I do to get rid of it?

[image]

Comment: I'd guess Visual Studio Code doesn't know Postgres syntax. May an extension can teach it? Maybe [this one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ckolkman.vscode-postgres)?

Comment: didn't work. interesting extension tho might play with that one later.

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction with teaching vscode the syntax that helped me google some other things and got an answer that worked.

Answer (score 4):

[Visual Studio Code vs SQL Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59802281/visual-studio-code-vs-sql-formatting)
vscode
Win: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> / Mac: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
And then type "Change Language Mode".
Then type 'postgresql'

Answer (score 2):

Besides @frogtoprincejs's answer, you could also rename your "*.sql" files to "*.psql" so VS Code will automatically interpret it as PostgreSQL